# Is there a ts (text search) function would return found string instead of boolean?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I am using PostgreSQL to find out the matched string in the article by using `tsvector` and `tsquery`.

I read the PostgreSQL manual 12.3 Controlling Text Search but nothing could help me to get the exact output I wanted.

Query:

```
SELECT ts_headline('english',
  'The most common type of search
is to find all documents containing given query terms
and return them in order of their similarity to the
query.',
  to_tsquery('query & similarity'),
  'StartSel = <, StopSel = >');
```

#### ts_headline output

```
The most common type of search
is to find all documents containing given <query> terms
and return them in order of their <similarity> to the
<query>.
```

#### I'm looking for the only string as mentioned below:

query, similarity

Comment: containing given <query> terms
 and return them in order of their <similarity> to the
 <query>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pick delimiters for StartSel and StopSel that you are sure do not exist elsewhere in the string, then it is pretty easy to do this with [a regexp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

```
 SELECT  distinct regexp_matches[1] from
     regexp_matches(
        ts_headline('english',
  'The most common type of search
is to find all documents containing given query terms
and return them in order of their similarity to the
query.',
            to_tsquery('query & similarity'),
            'StartSel = <, StopSel = >'
         ),
         '<(.*?)>','g'
     );
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what exactly I need! But I thought there is a function in PostgreSQL that could implement something like this!

Comment: That *is* a function in PostgreSQL, just not from ts* family.  You can tweak the options of ts_headline to get closer to what you want, but not close enough I think.